# Scheduled job process_mailing does not complete

Tags: mosaico, sparkpost, flexmailer

Running process_mailing scheduled job via 'execute now' starts but does not complete.

The first 200ish mails were sent then sending stopped.  Running 'Execute now' a few more times has now sent 330 of around 2000 recipients.

Some other mailing that were scheduled later have completed.

There are no errors reported in the Civi log.

One possibility is that it is running out of memory, but it is now not processing any further mails from this mailing which suggests there is something else going on.  Any hints or clues for debugging this?

CiviCRM 5.19.1
Mosaico 2.3.1572289217 
Flexmailer 1.1.0
Sparkpost 1.3

(There are a few related questions on SE, but with significant differences, or no answers.)

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues recently, after I have manually ran some random scheduled jobs forcefully.

Later I have changed the time of the scheduled job, specially for the ones that runs daily, to the default (12:00).

Since then my issue resolved. I would suggest try that.